# Is there any way to get the predictive text like in Intellij on Android Studio without having to press buttons?

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to coding and the predictive text (dropdown) on Intellij has made it alot easier and faster for me to learn.

I know Android studio is based off Intellij so is there any way to get the predictive text dropdown on android studio?

I know you can do it already by clicking a few buttons but im looking to replicate the feel of intellij as ive gotten so used to it

thanks

Comment: Are you not getting them? They should be the same as in IntelliJ by default.

Comment: Follow this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: May be u r using an older version of Android studio. Predictive texts works mostly like IntelliJ, I have worked on both You can also try checking your keyMap.